# How to solve Invalid JSON Primitive error on Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, webmethod

I am trying to perform ajax using webmethod on Asp.net,

And I am using **JQuery-3.1.1**

I want to pass the value to server and get back the value. I don't know what I did wrong.

**Asp.net Code**

```
<div class="row">
   <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-info"  Text="save" />
</div>
```

**Jquery Code**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btnSave').click(function () {
        var name= 'xxx';

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "AjaxWebMethod.aspx/getFileExistOrNot",
            data: '{fileName:'+name+'}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: OnSuccess,
            failure: function (response) {
                alert("failed ="+response.d);
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert("error ="+response.d);  //This alert is executing
            }
        });

        function OnSuccess(response) {
            alert("Result ="+response.d.mydata);
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

**C# code**

```
public partial class AjaxWebMethod : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    [WebMethod]
    public static string getFileExistOrNot(string fileName)
    {
        string mydata="ajaxworking";
        return mydata;
    }
}
```

> I don't know really where I did my mistake

**Error message on console**

> {Message: "Invalid JSON primitive: xxx.",…}
>
> ExceptionType:"System.ArgumentException"
>
> Message:"Invalid JSON primitive: xxx."

Can you give the solution with proper reason. that will good for me to understand more, thanks

Comment: `string mydata="ajaxworking";` is not valid JSON

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your postData is invalid JSON, a string needs quotes around it:

```
'{fileName:'+name+'}'
```

It should be:

```
 '{fileName:"'+name+'"}'
```

Comment: thanks. Can you tell me the difference of get and post method in jquery on your update answer?. thanks once again

Comment: @mohamedfaiz, if you have a new question, you should post it as a new question, not ask it in comments. It is only fair to the one who answered that you accept their answer, if it answers the *original* question.

Comment: Get doesn't allow you to post data, you can only send what's on the url which is less secure and the length is limited. If you need to post data to server it's best to use post, post also allows large amounts of data: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp

Comment: @trincot I am ready accept his answer, But Stackoverflow ask me to wait for another five min to accept answer.

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery call that you are making is set up to expect JSON format in the response.  It would appear that your server side code is simply returning a string which is not encoded as JSON.  You either need to change the output from the server or change what is expected from the ajax invocation.